# Creating Notifications upon New Data?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, push-notification, notifications

I'm building a react-native application which syncs with server every 20 seconds and updates it's data if a new content is available. But now, I want to set up notifications in my app so that whenever there is a new data it triggers a notification to inform user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You NEED to setup push notifications. I recommend [onesignal.com](http://onesignal.com) as it has a very easy and straight forward setup.

Answer (score 0):

For triggering notifications, you canuse react-native-fcm module that provide simple implementation and usage.
You have to use  node-fcm module at your server side from where you will trigger the notifications.
For this you need to create account on google firebase and add android and ios apps.
The documention is available in docs of react-native-fcm.[link](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm)

Comment: thank you, but I'm looking for a solution without adding server code. How is it possible to do this with adding as less as possible server code? @Prince

Comment: You need to add server code as, like if there is change at server when your app is closed in device then you have to send a notification to user's device that new data is arrived at server etc etc.
And same code will be used  for you when app is open and new data arrives at server, then you send notification to user's device, at that time your app is open and you have to decide what to display to the user when notification arrives.